# How to refactor this nested try-catch

Tags: php, refactoring, try-catch

I am new to try-catch and have been refactoring lots of code recently to keep up with the principle of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). However, I still have a few scenarios that I can't quite work out. For example, in the multi-lingual application I'm working on, I want to let the user set the interface language by passing the two-letter country code in the query string of a URL, or let the application use the default language if the user hasn't requested one:

```
// Which language shall we use?
$language = new language();
if(isset($_GET['language_code'])){
    try {
        $language->set_by_language_code($_GET['language_code']);
    } catch(e_language_not_found $e){
        try {
            $language->set_default_language();
            // TODO - use 'e_language_not_found' to display an error in the default language
        } catch(Exception $e){
            exit('No default language found');
        }
    }
} else {
    try {
        $language->set_default_language();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        exit('No default language found');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have repeated the `set_default_language()` block when a user hasn't requested any language at all. How can I refactor the code so that I call that method only once in the application? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate for **Code Review Beta**: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if the user hasn't request any language I guess language_code won't be set to the second set_default_language() will be called, to solve it you can add another condition to the while language setting. however I don't get what you question has to to with nested try-catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you're calling the function in two places is not bad per se. It doesn't affect performance, and refactoring it could make code less readable.

This is what I've come up with for your code:

```
// Which language shall we use?
$language = new language();
try {
  try {
    if(isset($_GET['language_code'])){
      $language->set_by_language_code($_GET['language_code']);
    } else {
      $language->set_default_language();     
    }
  } catch(e_language_not_found $e){    
      $language->set_default_language();    
  }
} catch (Exception $e){
  exit('No default language found');
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I still need a try-catch for each the set_default_language() calls?

Comment: As far as I can tell this code is equivalent to yours. The external `try{}catch(Exception $e)` will handle all exceptions from `set_default_language()` no matter where they are thrown.

Comment: Thanks @Mchl, so as long as `set_default_language()` threw an `e_default_language_not_found` exception instead of a generic exception, I could catch that in the external block?

Comment: Well... yes, since all exceptions extend `Exception` class anyway. I don't think however this would be very clear.

Comment: Thanks again. Why I love SO - two different approaches in the space of 10 minutes!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should implement these methods in your `language` class:

- `language::hasLanguage()` which returns a boolean value indicating the existence of a language (without throwing an exception!)
- `language::getDefLang()` which returns the default language identifier.

```
// Which language shall we use?
$language = new language();

// fallback
$langToSet = $language->getDefLang();

// use the passed language identifier if it exists
$passedLangId = isset($_GET['language_code']) ? $_GET['language_code'] : NULL;
if ($passedLangId !== NULL && $language->hasLanguage($passedLangId)) {
  $langToSet = $passedLangId;
}

try {
  $language->set_by_language_code($langToSet);
}
catch(Exception $e){
  exit('No default language found');
}
```

You should also specify a more detailed `Exception` type for the `catch` block.

You could also replace the `try...catch` block by using `language::hasLanguage()` in an `if` statement.

Comment: Defintely a nicer way to go

Comment: As written, I'd still need to have a try-catch and exception within the getDefLang() method in case the default language wasn't found, which just moves this logic to a different container - is that what you meant?

Comment: @boatingcow The point is that a) you only call `set_by_language_code()` once (DRY) and b) you therefore have only one `try...catch` block. You could also replace it by using `hasLanguage()` (as written in the edit). You should decide whether the "does exist" logic should be stored in the `language` class or in the user code.